# How to create single-custom.php for different repeater fields (using Advanced Custom Fields) in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using **Advanced Custom Fields Pro** with **Wordpress 4.1.1**

I feel like this should be pretty easy but I've been struggling with it.

The example I'll start with is I have a "Team" page that has a repeater with:

- Profile Image
- Name
- Job title
- Short biography
- Email/social link

All as `sub_field`

I have everything working nicely in the page where all posts are display (the actual Team landing page) but I can't figure out how to get content for each employee to live in a `single-custom_template.php` with a permalink.

***tl;dr*** I want my repeater content to be able to navigate to a single post/page with it's own custom template. Click on "Dave" in the whole team page have it navigate to his bio page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would benefit in building a custom post type for "Teams" so you're not selecting a new custom template (single-custome_"".php) each time you post another team member profile. This way also allows you to have all your custom meta fields organized under a single custom post-type.  However, if you don't want to go through all the trouble in creating a custom post-type, you can post each single team member page as a child page to your parent "Team" page, so that the url would look something like, "yourdomain.com/team/team-name, and then have all your custom meta fields auto populate when you select the single-custom_template.php in the "template" dropdown field.

Comment: I could do this or something like it. I guess I want to use ACF's repeater for my clients sake. It's more intuitive for them to navigate to a "Team" page and have a repeatable row for them to upload as many team member as they want.

If I go with custom post types instead of repeater, I still want to know how to put single repeater posts in their own page. I'm sure this issue will come up for me again.